# How to frame wall for a long drain plumbing

Tags: plumbing, framing, drain, structural

**UPDATE 1:** Added pic for my "idea"

I am building a new office structure inside my warehouse. The structure is 10'x30' and one side is against the existing wall. The other side is next to a restroom.

[image]

The red line is the drain connecting a new sink (right) to existing sink (left).

Here is another view of the new sink

[image]

I have two questions:

1. How to frame the wall so that the plumbing can be run without drilling holes to every single stud?

I am thinking of attaching two 2x4 sills on top and bolt to existing wall studs. Then below it is just "whatever" frame as it is no longer a load bearing wall since it's not supporting anything. Then I could just frame it for the top part while the bottom 3' will be "empty". Thought?

Something like this?

[image]

2. What would be the slope for 30' long drain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Double stud wall with space in the middle (lose a lot of space just to hide a pipe)

1a. - don't hide the pipe in the wall - run it on the surface, exposed. Put it on the warehouse side surface if you'd prefer not to see it inside the office room.

2. 30 foot long = 7.5 inches (1/4 inch per foot.) If the actual distance of the pipe is longer (because it goes 30 feet and turns a corner to get to the sink, and goes into the bathroom a few feet) more, at 1/4 inch per foot.

2a: you'll need a new vent for that new sink.

Comment: Actually exposed plumbing is not possible because I have shelving right against the wall. Plus it’s a working / office area. It will be ugly

Answer (score 2):

If with "ledger" you mean a "sill" of 2x6 with edges against the studs, above the pipe for the top of a box that reaches the floor, then yes that would work.

It does not have to be load bearing, just strong enough to carry its weight, plus whatever you place on top of it in the office or in the warehouse side, and to support its finishing (drywall panel).

That sill can be 2x4 (giving you 3.5in space for the pipe, or it can be a 2x4 ledger (fastened flat against the studs) onto which you attach a separate 1x6 sill. This kind of L-shaped support is easier to build firmly, than trying to attach a sill's edge against the studs.

You can then add a bottom sill, screwed into the (concrete) floor, and vertically span strapping (e.g. 1x3 flat) for drywall panel support of the box.

How much strapping you need for stiffness of the wall finishing depends on the height of the box. If using 1x strapping and it's only 2 to 3 feet high, you'll need something every 16 or 24in.

The strapping will also help hold the top sill. Should you need more weight support for the box, you can support the sill by direct bearing it on the vertical lumber. Strapping should then be 2x instead of 1x lumber.

How high the top of this box is depends on the pipe's rise (about a foot) plus the height of its connection under the existing sink. Maybe it's 2 feet total from floor to finished top.

You can increase it to 30..36 inches high so that it can be support for a counter-top high working surface inside the office or on the warehouse side.

Remember to slope the pipe at 1in per 4 feet, and add a vent at the second sink. (Of course, the box would not be sloped). The vent can be added from the ceiling, connecting to the vent for the existing sink, or it can be an AAV (air admittance valve).

Comment: I am not sure if I followed everything you said about strapping. But I added my own thinking's diagram. Basically the drain pipe will run within the box of around 2 feet height. The bottom 1 foot will be just framing so drywall can attach to. Thought?

Comment: As drawn, that new 30ft long horizontal gap you have in the wall framing is problematic and will not transfer load. Where is it "bolted"? (That could work too).   Would be good to put strapping in that space, around the pipe, for drywall support.